# To stream file data directly from Dropbox to webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to stream data from my Dropbox to webpage in real time, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: What type of data? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea because Dropbox can throttle speed, stop sharing file when using from many locations.

You can install Dropbox to your server and sync some folder with your Dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/install
And to stream from your local folder is easier task.

But if you really need to get files from Dropbox real-time, you can use their API. They've got libraries for many languages. For example this one is for PHP, also tutorial there:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php